# What constitute "visited countries" in Schengen in a US visa application?

Tags: visas, usa, schengen

Currently I am living in Germany as an Asian student. I am going to fill up a US visa application (DS 160).  On the form they asked for the countries I have visited. As I have a Schengen visa, I have travelled in almost six countries in Europe although there is no proof in passport (as there is often no border inside Schengen).

In the form should I write all Schengen countries that I have visited or only Germany?

Comment: THE WHOLE TRUTH.

Comment: AND NOTHING BUT THE TRUTH.

Comment: SO HELP ME GOD.

Comment: USE A SEPARATE SHEET TO LIST THEM IF NEEDED

Answer (score 12):

Any country you have visited should be listed, whether or not you have a stamp.

There might be some doubt about countries you have only transited at the airport, or only passed through on a train or bus without stopping, but that does not seem to apply in your case.

Comment: Look at what happened with Snowden.  He was not allowed to 'enter' Russia until his status had been resolved, so they kept him at the airport.

Comment: If you clear immigration, and was land side on any country, where you "were" free to roam around, you was in that country, and you "visited", however it might be few hours or days or weeks. In case of Schengen, if you took flight from Berlin to parus, then bus to Brussels, and then train to Amsterdam, and flight to iut of Schengen, you visited Germany, France, Belgium, Netherlands.